# Multi-values needs to be exported to excel to different rows using lotus script

Tags: lotus-notes, lotus-domino, lotusscript

I was trying to export the Multi-valued field but couldn't able to achieve it. i tried Ubound to export but the scenario is I need the 1st value in 1st row and 2nd value in 2nd row vice versa. Please help me to solve this. I'm using excel application to export the data.

Thanks in advance.

```
ForAll b In fieldList 
If UBound(doc.getitemvalue(b)) <1 Then 

worksheet.cells(i,j).value =doc.getitemvalue(CStr(b)) 

Else 

'Join(doc.getitemvalue(CStr(b)),Chr(10)) 

worksheet.cells(i,j).value =Join(doc.getitemvalue(CStr(b)),Chr(10)) 

End If 
End Forall
```

Comment: Sorry, I do not understand your question: Should every value be in a separate cell (rows are increasing) or withing the same cell but divided by newline characters?. Please add your calculation of i and j to your example code, that might make it clearer...

Comment: The values needs to be stored in a separate cell (new rows) but its separating as new line in a same cell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lets assume the following document:

| Fieldname | Value 0 | Value 1 | Value 2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| FirstField | Value0-First |  |  |
| SecondField | Value0-Second | Value1-Second | Value2-Second |
| ThirdField | Value0-Third | Value1-Third |  |

**Solution 1:**
If you want the result to look like this

| FirstField | SecondField | ThirdField |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Value0-First | Value0-Second | Value0-Third |
|  | Value1-Second | Value1-Third |
|  | Value2-Second |  |

Then you use the following code:

```
cellY = 2
cellX = 1
Forall fieldName in fieldNameList
  For y = 0 to ubound( doc.GetitemValue( fieldName ) )
    worksheet.cells(cellY + y, cellX).value = doc.GetitemValue( fieldName )(y)
  Next
  cellX = cellX + 1
End Forall
```

**Solution 2**: If you want the result to look like this

| Fieldname | Value 0 | Value 1 | Value 2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| FirstField | Value0-First |  |  |
| SecondField | Value0-Second | Value1-Second | Value2-Second |
| ThirdField | Value0-Third | Value1-Third |  |

Then you use the following code:

```
cellY = 1
cellX = 2
Forall fieldName in fieldNameList
  For x = 0 to ubound( doc.GetitemValue( fieldName ) )
    worksheet.cells(cellY, cellX+x).value = doc.GetitemValue( fieldName )(x)
  Next
  cellY = cellY + 1
End Forall
```

**Solution 3:**
If you want the result to look like this

| All fields |
| --- |
| FirstField |
| Value0-First |
| SecondField |
| Value0-Second |
| Value1-Second |
| Value2-Second |
| ThirdField |
| Value0-Third |
| Value1-Third |

Then you use the following code:

```
cellY = 1
cellX = 1
Forall fieldName in fieldNameList
  worksheet.cells(cellY, cellX).value = fieldName
  For y = 0 to ubound( doc.GetitemValue( fieldName ) )
    cellY = cellY + 1
    worksheet.cells(cellY, cellX).value = doc.GetitemValue( fieldName )(y)
  Next
  cellY = cellY + 1
End Forall
```

Answer (score 3):

Create a loop that goes through all the values for each field by index ("*x*" in my code sample). Use *x* again to offset the row value.

You will have a problem that each *fieldName*'s values will be overwritten in the spreadsheet, because *i* and *j* are always the same, so if you have more than one *fieldName* in your *fieldList* you will need to do something about that too. In my example, I have incremented *j* for each *fieldName* so that they will be in different spreadsheet columns

```
ForAll fieldName In fieldList

    For x = LBound(doc.getitemvalue(fieldName)) to Ubound(doc.getitemvalue(fieldName))
        worksheet.cells(i + x, j).value = doc.getitemvalue(fieldName)(x)
    Next

    j = j + 1
End Forall
```

Alternative version to achieve what you ask in your comment:

```
ForAll fieldName In fieldList

    For x = LBound(doc.getitemvalue(fieldName)) to Ubound(doc.getitemvalue(fieldName))
        worksheet.cells(i, j + x).value = doc.getitemvalue(fieldName)(x)
    Next

    i = i + 1
End Forall
```

Comment: I have tried with this code actually its adding the columns and writing values to 1st column,2nd column vice versa. my condition is to write the 1st value In 1st row 2nd value in 2nd row but in this case it writes all the values to the columns.

Comment: I have tried the above code @Phil M Jones , The expectation is the value needs to be in the below format
Title
1. Abc
2. Abc
3. Abc

But the actual code works like
Title
1.Abc,Abc,Abc

Comment: @keerthana: I don't understand you: The first codeblock puts the values each in a separate row, a separate column for every field. The second solution puts each value in a separate column and each field in a separate row... what variant is missing here?

Comment: @keerthana upload a picture of what you want the spreadsheet to look like and we may be able to help

Answer (score 1):

`doc.getitemvalue(CStr(b))` always returns a variant array, even when the `Ubound` is less than one.

The code in your `Then` clause needs to dereference the 0th entry of the array:

```
worksheet.cells(i,j).value =doc.getitemvalue(CStr(b))(0)
```

Comment: This works for the 1st if condition but else part it always write all the values present in the particular field

Comment: Yes, you are doing the Join function to write to a single field. The Join function concatenates all members of an Array of Strings and returns a string. That's literally what the first sentence of the help text for that function says. If you want the separate values from the array in separate cells, you will have to write a loop as per Phil M Jones' answer.